# VS 2005 Installer Project Version Number

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation

I am getting this error now that I hit version number 1.256.0:
Error   4   Invalid product version '1.256.0'. Must be of format '##.##.####'

The installer was fine with 1.255.0 but something with 256 (2^8) it doesn't like.  I found this stated on msdn.com:
The Version property must be formatted as N.N.N, where each N represents at least one and no more than four digits. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3ywkte8(VS.80).aspx)

Which would make me believe there is nothing wrong 1.256.0 because it meets the rules stated above.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this would be failing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article says there is a major and minor max of 255.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The link you reference says " This page is specific to Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/.NET Framework 3.5", but you're talking about vs2005.

My guess: a 0-based range of 256 numbers ends at 255, therefore trying to use 256 exceeds that and perhaps they changed it for VS2008

Edit: I looked again and see where that link can be switched to talk about VS2005, and gives the same answer.  I'm still sticking to my 0-255 theory though.  Wouldn't be the first time this week I came across something incorrect in MSDN docs.